# how to save page source from selenium (jupyter notebook) to a txt file on local drive?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

Below is my code:

```
r = driver.page_source
```

I want to save it as member_number.txt whereas member_number is a variable
I want to save it to "C:\Member Rerocrds\"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to save data in text file.

```
r=driver.page_source
member_number="variable_name"
f=open("C:\\Member Rerocrds\\" +  member_number + ".txt","w")
f.write(r)
f.close()
```